# I can't install gcloud on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-14.04, gcloud-node

Please Can you help me solve this problem  [image]

NB: "npm install jsonfile" work perfectly

Comment: It looks like your hard disk is out of space (as indicated by the error `ENOSPC: no space left on device`).

Comment: No , I have space enough 
i get this error :
npm ERR! Linux 3.14.32-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "gcloud"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3

Comment: The output in your new comment doesn't match what you have in the screenshot (your screenshot shows Node v4.x and npm v2.14.x, but your comment suggests otherwise). Can you upload a newer screenshot with the complete output?

Comment: i update the screenshot

Comment: I have reviewed the screenshot and it does seem that you really do not have enough space on the server. Could you try running the command `df -h` to double check?

Comment: the result ;

root@ns3004961:/home/Wefid_API# df -h
Sys. de fichiers Taille UtilisÃ© Dispo Uti% MontÃ© sur
/dev/root           20G     14G  5,2G  72% /
devtmpfs            16G    4,0K   16G   1% /dev
none               4,0K       0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none               3,2G    1,4M  3,2G   1% /run
none               5,0M       0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                16G     12K   16G   1% /run/shm
none               100M       0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow           1,0M    8,0K 1016K   1% /tmp
/dev/md3           1,8T     14G  1,7T   1% /var

Comment: i would like send a screenshot but i don't know how

Comment: I noticed something, your `/tmp` somehow has only ~1 MB of space, that might not be enough for `npm` to store downloaded packages. Could you try running `npm config set tmp <some other directory on your root partition>`, then try again?